# JQuery .animate scrollTop not animating, just jumping to the desired location

Tags: jquery, animation, scroll

I have a single page application website that I am trying to use a anchored navigation menu, which scrolls down to certain sections of the page.

It works fine, but when I click the link...no transition animation happens, it just jumps to the desired section.

```
$('a').click(function(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop:  $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
}, 700);
return false;
```

});

This is the JQuery I am using....what do I change/add to make it transition properly.

Comment: Can you write the HTML code as well?

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me. Why not imitate or test it on your end. I assume that you have some attribute error on your HTML. That is why it is not working smoothly. Another reason is, you have an error in javascript before the click function of the  tag which disables all the lines below the error code

HTML

```
<p id="top">I'm on top</p>
<a id="test" href="#top">Click me</a>
```

JS

```
$('a').click(function(){
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop:  $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
  }, 700);
  return false;
});
```

CSS

```
#test {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 1000px;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried you're solution, but it still doesn't work. I'll keep tinkering. Thanks for you're help :)